# Restrict header to show on particular view page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a simple question and i want the best approach for it.

**If header is a partial view and i want to render it on every page then i defined in _layout view page and it start showing on every page.What should i do now for a particular page like welcome Screen page where i don't want to show any header footer.**

I want to restrict header and footer for only one page that is welcome screen page.It should not render on that page.

One way i have thought of is not to define header footer partial view in layout section. just define it on every page. but i think this approach is not good.There should be some solution,Please suggest me.

Comment: Create a different layout for the Welcome page without the header and footer

Comment: Just create an empty view without choosing a `layout page`. Be aware not to delete the C# code where it says `Layout = null;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please add below code in your page, which you don't want to show header and footer.

**View**

```
 <script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $('header').empty();
         $('footer').empty();
     });
 </script>
```

**_Layout**

```
<body> 
   <header>
       test1
   </header>
    <footer>
        test2
    </footer>
</body>
```

OR

**_Layout**

```
<div class="HeaderFooter">Header text</div>
<div class="HeaderFooter">footer text</div>
```

**View**

```
 <script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $('.HeaderFooter').empty();
     });
 </script>
```

Let me know if any concern.